# Upgrading web.xml to 2.4 or above in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-7.2

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 version with APACHE tomcat 7.0.27.0 version server. I am trying to make a servlet file in my project but its showing the following message or error-

"Web application version is unsupported . Upgrade web.xml to version 2.4 or newer or use previous version of NetBeans."

How can i fix it please reply-

Comment: Any one please answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this Problem and I solved it in a rather curious way. I removed the web.xml file, Created the servlet and replaced the web.xml file and it worked.

I would recommend you get Better Solution from the http://forums.netbeans.org/